# Unable to generate the documentation using apiDocjs

Tags: api, parsing, documentation, comments, api-doc

Went through couple of tutorials and documentations, 
including main documentation [here](http://apidocjs.com).Following it, created two files :

1) example.js

```
var currentUser={
name='Mary'
};
/**
* @api {get} /user/ Request User information
* @apiName GetUser
* @apiGroup User
*/

function getUser(){
 return {code 200,data:currentUser};
}
function setName(name){
    if(name.length==0){
      return {code:404,message:'NameEmptyError'};
    }
currentUser.name=name;
return {code 204};
}
```

2) testpython.py

```
"""
@api {get} /user/ Request User information
@apiName GetUser
@apiGroup User
"""
print "hello"
```

Saved both of them in a folder, say "my_project".
On mac terminal, went to parent directory of "my_project".
Ran the script :

```
apidoc -i my_project/ -o apidoc/
```

Getting error :

```
 - ERROR - Failed to parse sources
```

It's basic, but somehow, not getting success.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This happens when you install package both, from npm and pip3. Clear the currently installed apiDoc packages completely.
To remove npm package, to go terminal and type :

```
cd /usr/local/lib/node_modules
```

Then to uninstall it, type :

```
sudo npm uninstall apidoc
```

This will remove the npm-apidoc package.
To remove the pip3 package :

```
sudo pip3 uninstall apidoc
```

To remove them manually , to go :

```
/usr/local/lib/pythonVERSION/dist-packages
```

Now for fresh install:

```
sudo npm install apidoc -g
```

This should do it :).